# The 'image.find' command of Images Addon is not working properly

Tags: g1ant

I am using this code which is supposed to download and open an image on my screen and then the G1ant software is supposed to search if the image popped up on my screen or not. Problem is the image did pop up but the program outputs 'The image was not found in the search area'. How can I fix this?

My code is-

```
♥image = ♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\image.png

file.download https://jeremykun.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/img49.png filename ♥image

program ♥image

image.find ♥image result ♥point relative false

dialog ♥point
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you wait for the program that is responsible to open your image to load and display the image? Use `wait true` argument of program command and do not use the image name as the application to run, rather do something similar to this:

```
♥imagePath = ‴♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Documents\some image.png‴

program ‴C:\Program Files\paint.net\paintdotnet.exe‴ arguments "♥imagePath" wait true

image.find ♥imagePath result ♥point relative false

dialog ♥point
```

Also, isn't your image opened scaled?